# containerd and kubernetes container will be down randomly

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I installed `kuber 1.25` when I run `kubeadm config images pull` , It fetched the following images:

```
> crictl images
IMAGE                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/pause                          3.6                 6270bb605e12e       302kB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns           v1.9.3              5185b96f0becf       14.8MB
registry.k8s.io/etcd                      3.5.4-0             a8a176a5d5d69       102MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver            v1.25.1             b09a3dc327be2       34.2MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.25.1             4d904f9df20a0       31.3MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.25.2             dbfceb93c69b6       31.3MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.25.1             3ed3cb68c861e       20.3MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.25.2             1c7d8c51823b5       20.3MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler            v1.25.1             4df0903523686       15.8MB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.8                 4873874c08efc       311kB
```

My problem are explained in the following ps :

```
root@debian:~# crictl ps 
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED              STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
57ea1fbf9a290       a8a176a5d5d69       42 seconds ago       Running             etcd                      1876                d29bb8c1c84d3       etcd-debian
9ae0603c3489b       3ed3cb68c861e       59 seconds ago       Running             kube-proxy                117                 e259b18a6b09b       kube-proxy-8t2mz
9e5d71a57430a       4df0903523686       About a minute ago   Running             kube-scheduler            132                 07b6133ee8f16       kube-scheduler-debian
6fbf351ab72d3       4d904f9df20a0       About a minute ago   Running             kube-controller-manager   124                 b25394a8165e9       kube-controller-manager-debian
627fdc8f37984       b09a3dc327be2       2 minutes ago        Running             kube-apiserver            123                 b510c0c32211d       kube-apiserver-debian
root@debian:~# crictl ps 
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED              STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
57ea1fbf9a290       a8a176a5d5d69       50 seconds ago       Running             etcd                      1876                d29bb8c1c84d3       etcd-debian
9ae0603c3489b       3ed3cb68c861e       About a minute ago   Running             kube-proxy                117                 e259b18a6b09b       kube-proxy-8t2mz
9e5d71a57430a       4df0903523686       About a minute ago   Running             kube-scheduler            132                 07b6133ee8f16       kube-scheduler-debian
6fbf351ab72d3       4d904f9df20a0       About a minute ago   Running             kube-controller-manager   124                 b25394a8165e9       kube-controller-manager-debian
627fdc8f37984       b09a3dc327be2       2 minutes ago        Running             kube-apiserver            123                 b510c0c32211d       kube-apiserver-debian
root@debian:~# crictl ps 
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED              STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
57ea1fbf9a290       a8a176a5d5d69       51 seconds ago       Running             etcd                      1876                d29bb8c1c84d3       etcd-debian
9e5d71a57430a       4df0903523686       About a minute ago   Running             kube-scheduler            132                 07b6133ee8f16       kube-scheduler-debian
6fbf351ab72d3       4d904f9df20a0       About a minute ago   Running             kube-controller-manager   124                 b25394a8165e9       kube-controller-manager-debian
627fdc8f37984       b09a3dc327be2       2 minutes ago        Running             kube-apiserver            123                 b510c0c32211d       kube-apiserver-debian
root@debian:~# crictl ps 
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED              STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
57ea1fbf9a290       a8a176a5d5d69       52 seconds ago       Running             etcd                      1876                d29bb8c1c84d3       etcd-debian
9e5d71a57430a       4df0903523686       About a minute ago   Running             kube-scheduler            132                 07b6133ee8f16       kube-scheduler-debian
6fbf351ab72d3       4d904f9df20a0       About a minute ago   Running             kube-controller-manager   124                 b25394a8165e9       kube-controller-manager-debian
627fdc8f37984       b09a3dc327be2       2 minutes ago        Running             kube-apiserver            123                 b510c0c32211d       kube-apiserver-debian
root@debian:~# crictl ps
```

Sometimes some container will be down. And sometimes the given container will be up.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you experiencing control plane pods restarts frequently?  if yes you can check pod logs to know the more details of the issue.

Comment: Would you please more in depth?

Comment: In container world container process going up & down is common.  when pod get deployed  the corresponding  container process will come up and when pods get deleted the respective container process will do down.  to check pod restarts you can run kubectl get pods -n kube-system which will give information about pod status and restart details.  to check particular pod logs please run kubectl logs <pod-name> -n <namespace>

Comment: with `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` I get the `The connection to the server 192.168.0.120:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` Because kube-apiserver is down. When my services down, I can't run `kubectl`

Comment: Pls check container logs using journalctl -xe which will give more details  trust you had ran run following commands after creating the cluster.  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube, sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config.  these commands will ensure to present the certs to connect to api server using kubectl.   Also ensure network is created.

Comment: @PersianGulf If your issue is resolved plese post it. So, that it will be helpful for other community members

Comment: @Rameshkollisetty , Unfortunately it didn't resolve. Do you have any idea for solving it?

Comment: @PersianGulf What error currentlu you are getting and have  you enabled any preemption?